# AddThis - How to load the 16px icon set?

Tags: icons, addthis

How can I load the 16px icon set in the iframe popup (the screen which shows after pressing the "Share" button")?

I know its possible because I've seen it on a demo on their own site:- http://www.addthis.com/pages/iframe-example-meta

I noticed they had class="addthis_16x16_style" so I've set that in my code too, but it still doesn't work.

My source code uses:

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_16x16_style">
    <a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_facebook_send"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
</div>
```

When I click "Share" I always get the large icons.

As it's loading inside an iframe is it even possible for me to control that? (Changing the class with firebug inside the iframe does load the small icons Im wanting to use)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page you referenced is using an older version of AddThis.  To use the older version of AddThis, you need to change your JS include from:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-4ee0224503c60b3d"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/**250**/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-4ee0224503c60b3d"></script>
```

The only warning is that we're trying to get people to upgrade to the newer version which has a much higher sharing rate, so using the older version isn't recommended.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using AddThis in an iframe with very limited screen space available and just think the smaller icons work better for this particular project :)